# return static_cast<int> C++ and C

Tags: c++, c

I would like to know about C and C++ language.

C++ uses:

```
return static_cast<int>
```

How can I transform `return static_cast<int>`to C?

For example:

- C `printf()`
- C++ `cout`

Comment: static_cast<type*>(x) -> (type*)x

Comment: Your English is fine, but please look at the preview and click the `{}` formatting button so your post isn't garbled.

Comment: What would be difficult to transform in C is `dynamic_cast<SomeType*>(somevar)`

Answer (score 8):

C style casting is simply prefixing the value with the type in parentheses. Instead of

```
static_cast<type>(value)
```

you simply do

```
(type)value
```

e.g.

```
static_cast<int>(x)
```

becomes

```
(int)x
```

Or you could do

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
    #define STATIC_CAST(Type_, Value_) static_cast<Type_>(Value_)
#else
    #define STATIC_CAST(Type_, Value_) (Type_)(Value_)
#endif
```

and use one invocation for both languages

```
STATIC_CAST(int, x) // C++ static_cast<int>(x), C (int)(x)
```

The extra parentheses in the C version around the Value_ aren't required for simple cases but are there because this is a macro and if you said

```
STATIC_CAST(int, 1.0 + 2.0)
```

you don't want it to expand to

```
(int)1.0 + 2.0
```

but want it to expand to

```
(int)(1.0 + 2.0)
```

Note that C++ allows the C form of casting but the templated cast mechanism is preferred by C++ engineers.

Comment: NB: C allows you to cast almost anything to anything else. There is no safety mechanism except for things that make utterly no sense.

Comment: @Potatoswatter, wrong. In C you can *only* cast basic types, pointers and `enum`, nothing else.

Comment: @JensGustedt The only remaining types besides that list are arrays, structures, unions, and `void`. Optionally there are also atomics and complex numbers which I suppose may be casted. You can cast from array to pointer, or from anything to `void`. The remaining cases are disallowed as they have no conceptual basis, i.e. make no sense.

Comment: @Potatoswatter, it just sounded as gratuitous C bashing to me. Exactly, the same thing applies to C++, if you do the corresponding casts in C++ there is no safety mechanism, either. That's the nature of casts. In fact, in C++ you can cast much more (with more fine grained mechanisms), in particular between `struct` or `class`, and so the macro as presented here is even more "dangerous" for C than for C++. So what is the point of such a remark?

Comment: The C-style casting is less fine-grained and more brute-force, which isn't mostly a maintenance headache; C++ style lets you be more specific and more likely to result in compile error/warn if you 'break' the type/properties of a paramter/var chain. For instance, C casting will let you do `const char* p = "hello"; int n = (int)p;` where we change from a numeric to a pointer type and discarded const. C++ casting would require you to explicitly remove the const and explicitly make the pointer-to-numeric transition. http://ideone.com/OkdB8j vs http://ideone.com/5voc5V